# Gazebo 11.14 Physics ContactManager Update Rate

Tags: c++, ros-noetic, gazebo-11

I am using Gazebo version 11.14.0 with ROS Noetic.
I searched in the Gazebo API documentation for the update rate of the physics contact manager:
`physics::ContactManager *contactManager = world->Physics()->GetContactManager();`

However, I did not find any information about the sampling rate.
Running `gz topic -z /gazebo/default/physics/contacts` gives different changing values.

Are there any release note or official documentation giving the update rate of the physics contact Manager of Gazebo?